# How to execute Shell commands in GNU/Linux

Tags: java, shell, tomcat, permissions, java-ee-7

I am creating a Web using JavaEE + Tomcat, and I would like to know what would be the best way to execute a GNU/Linux Shell command and, if possible, to know if there has been an error in the execution of the command.

How to manage if it is an administrative command for which I must have root permissions to execute it? For example, how to execute the following command that I normally execute as follows in the Shell:

```
#bash ~/my_script.sh
```

(with root permissions)

Comment: A couple of things: when you say "with root permission" do you mean that the app itself is not running as root and you need to run the script as root? Also, when you say "if there's been any error" you mean to retrieve it by the command itself returning a result not equal to zero or by analyzing its output?

Comment: "With root permission" I mean the command will have to mount a filesystem, for example, so I will need root permission. I don't know what permissions Tomcat will have.

Comment: "if there's been any error" I mean I want to know if it was possible to mount the partition, for example (yes, by the command itself returning a result not equal to zero)

Comment: I would do that at the OS level by either giving that user (whatever it will be) permission to mount a particular filesystem or by adding it to sudoers and calling the script as `sudo bash /path/to/my_script.sh`

Comment: About the return value, even simply running the script with `Runtime::exec()` will return a `Process` that has an `exitValue()` method that you can check .

Comment: The script will be launched when a user click on a button, so I don't think it will be useful (and no one will write the sudo password when "prompted")

Comment: In `sudoers` you can set that particular user to not require a password to run a specific command. Also, the user that clicks the button is not the user running Tomcat. Or is it?

Comment: The user running Tomcat will need to be in sudoers. I would arrange ```NOPASSWD``` just for that one particular command